# Tkinter: How do I get the value after clicking the button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to Tkinter and GUI in general, but I tried looking around for similar problems (and found some) and I still can't seem to get it to work. I want to save the stringpath "path_to_ifc_file" after clicking the button, so that I can use it in another script later on.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def BrowseFiles():
    path_to_ifc_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="../models/", title="Get Ifc-File:",
                                          filetypes=(("Ifc-Files", "*.ifc*"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    if path_to_ifc_file == "":
        label_file_explorer.configure(text="Get Ifc-File:")
    else:
        label_file_explorer.configure(text="Found Ifc-File: \n" + Path(path_to_ifc_file).stem + ".ifc")
    return path_to_ifc_file

# WINDOW CONFIGURATION
window = Tk()
window.title('Test')
window.geometry("800x280")

# INITIALIZE WIDGETS
label_file_explorer = Label(window, text="Get Ifc-File:")
button_explore = Button(window, text="Browse", command=BrowseFiles)

# DISPLAY WIDGETS
label_file_explorer.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_explore.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

In my mind I just want something like

```
path_to_ifc_file=<returned value path_to_ifc_file from function BrowseFiles()>
```

I appreciate every help I can get! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can't really return the value like that in a button function, You could try assigning it to a global variable or appending to a list or dictionary or if You were to use a `StringVar()` just set the value to the filename and use the instance

Comment: Ah ok, do you maybe have some kind of example code. Appending to a dictionary would be optimal I think...

Comment: well just create a dictionary or a list (bit easier) outside the function and instead of `return` append that item to the list (it doesn't require to declare the list as global)

Comment: appending it to the list workes perfectly! Thank you a lot!!!